# Let clients in a network find eachother

Tags: c#, networking, communication

I have multiple pc's in a network, they each need to get each other ipaddress, i looked at broadcasting, but this requiers a server, but all pc's need to find all other. can anyone kick me in the right direction on how this could be implemented?

Comment: Why can't your program be the server that broadcasts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a server is technically a client that just listen for connection most of the time or provides a service.

Now, if you want that all client should discover each other. The simple way to achieve that would be send Listen for `Broadcast Message` at a specific port and send a broadcast message in the network that will help other client know that a `EndPoint (Node)` is now active.

An example would be

1. Listen on port XXXX as client starts up.
2. Broadcast a message at port XXXX this will help other client discover the node.
3. Once the client receives a discovery message, it sends its own detail to the client from which it received the message!

Comment: So multiple clients can listen to a port and all can broadcast at it at the same time too?

Comment: one client per node, you cannot start 2 client on same PC, that would create error.

Comment: @Jeff Aye it's just a Peer to Peer network. Google UDP Peer to Peer, most are chat servers, but the principles are useful.